# Regulating voltage through non-inverting op-amp

Tags: operational-amplifier

I am building a CDI for my bike. The input voltage from the pulse coil of my bike is 150 mV at low RPMs, but increases to 20 V at higher RPMs.

I want to regulate the pulse voltage to 5 V at all RPMs. When I use a different pulse coil the input voltage at low RPMs is 3 V, but at higher RPMs it reaches 30-40 V. Generally, the pulse generated at low RPMs is 100-150 mV.

I though of adding a non-inverting op-amp circuit between the pulse coil and the microcontroller. The RPM range is 0-20000. The input is an AC pulse, so I thought of adding a diode between the pulse coil and pin 3 of the 741 op-amp.

Could anyone help me with the schematics?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a pretty simple way. First, use an LM324 op-amp since it can run off a single supply. Power it with the 5 volts you are using everywhere else. Ground the inverting pin. Run your signal to the non-inverting pin and also to ground through a diode like a 1N4001.

The diode will clip the pulses from the coil at about 700mV and the op-amp is used as a comparator and will saturate to almost 5V whenever the + input is higher than the - input, producing nice 5V pulses.

If the output is on all the time you can use a resistor divider and the 5V supply with the - input to adjust the level at which the comparator flips positive.

I am wondering about negative going pulses from the pickup. I would use two diodes in parallel (but facing opposite directions) across the pickup coil. This will limit the pulse to + or - 700mV and protect the rest of the circuit. Then perhaps AC couple to the + op-amp pin with a capacitor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a MOSFET like the IFP840 and use two bridge rectifiers, one for the gate, the other for the capacitor (second terminal).